# The controller does not return data to the ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a query from Model/registro.php, that returns  a value to me Controllers/registro.php which i must return  a data to ajax, but not it does.
What could be the problem  fro which the Controllers/registro.php
does no return anything to the succes:function(data) ajax

*Model/registro.php*

```
public function registrar($username,$email,$password,$confirm_password)
{




     try{

                $this->has= crypt($password);
                $this->has_con= crypt($confirm_password);
                $p= true;

                $registro=$this->conexion->conexion->query("insert into registro_por (nombre, correo, pass, conf_pass) values( '$username','$email','$this->has','$this->has_con')");


                 if($registro)
                 {
                         return $p;

                 }else{

                    throw new Exception("Fallos la ejecución");

                 }



     }catch(Exception $e){

             echo 'Message: '.$e->getMessage();

     }






 }
```

*Controllers/registro.php*

```
require_once("../Model/registro.php");

  $username =$_POST["username"];
  $email =$_POST["email"];
  $password =$_POST["password"];
  $confirm_password =$_POST["confirm_password"];


 $reg = new Registro();

 $t=$reg->registrar($username,$email,$password,$confirm_password);  
  $respuesta="soy controllers";
  $fail="segenero un erro";
 //var_dump($t);
 //echo ($t); 
if($t == true){
    //return "ok";
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($respuesta);

}else{
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($fail);
    //echo "fail";
    //echo json_encode("fail");
 }
```

*Ajax jquery*

```
$('#register-submit').click(function(){


  var data= $('#register-form').serialize();

    $.ajax({
             beforeSend:function(){
                console.log(data);
             },
             type:'POST',
             url:'../Controllers/registro.php',
             data:data,
             dataType:"json",
             success: function(data){
                   console.log('nanananana');
                   console.log("soy data"+data);
             }

       });

 });
```

Comment: Could be any number of things. Start by preventing the default form submit. Page will refresh if `$('#register-submit')` is a submit button and you don't prevent submit. Then you need to inspect actual request in browser dev tools for clues and errors

Comment: what kind of error did you get ? `error: function(err){ console.log(err); }`

Comment: It shows no mistake, because the model / registro.php performs the insert, and returns response to the controller, but the Controller / registro.php not return to the jquery ajax the  data

Comment: @DiegoMariani the error console show me  undefined in console.log(err)

Comment: did you add that after the `success` function inside `ajax` object ?

Comment: we can't help you without any debug information

Comment: yo agregue error: function(err){   console.log(err);  console shows me Object {readyState: 0, responseJSON: undefined, status: 0, statusText: "error"}

Answer (score 1):

Try stoping the submit event using `e.preventDefault();`

```
$('#register-submit').click(function(){

   e.preventDefault();

   var data= $('#register-form').serialize();

    $.ajax({
         ....
     });

});
```

Here is mentioned the same case

[jquery ajax jqXHR.status is always 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14313283/jquery-ajax-jqxhr-status-is-always-0)

Comment: the mistake happened because the button had type="submit",the which cause the event click to the button  never cancelled.
changing  type="submit" by type="button",  everything works.

Thank you all for you messages,helped me  a lot.

Comment: exactly, if you use type="submit" you need cancel the submit event, but if you change it to type=button isn´t necesary

Comment: yes, i forgot a little  the html,jajaj sometimes happens